# Accessing Cygwin paths from Scala REPL

Tags: scala, cygwin, read-eval-print-loop

I'm setting up Scala on my Windows machine, and trying to run it from Cygwin.  I'm able to launch a REPL and execute commands, but when I tried to pre-load a file (`-i`) I was told the file didn't exist:

```
$ scala -i /home/username/preload.scala
That file does not exist

Welcome to Scala version 2.11.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM, Java 1.7.0_02).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Now, the file does exist in the terminal:

```
$ [ -f /home/username/preload.scala ] && echo EXISTS
EXISTS
```

But Scala can't find it.  It turns out, Scala is using the Windows directory root, rather than Cygwin's:

```
scala> Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/")).asScala.foreach{println}
\$Recycle.Bin
\cygwin
\Documents and Settings
\Drivers
\Program Files
\Program Files (x86)
\ProgramData
\Recovery
\System Volume Information
\Users
\Windows
```

But now I'm at a bit of a loss.  How can I tell the Scala REPL to use Cygwin paths, or conversely how can I configure Cygwin to properly launch Scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Some cygwin conversion is done in the launcher script, for classpaths, but it doesn't do file arguments.

Consider scala file.scala and scala pkg.Main as ambiguous.

Edit: maybe it's worth a feature request, since, besides -i handling, you can try to detect file paths to convert (slashes and colons).

(This is the same condition from plain Java, of course.)

Comment: Wow, I guess I've never run into needing absolute paths with Java (e.g. `javac /tmp/Test.java` fails).

Answer (score 0):

This is, sadly, expected behavior, as detailed on the [Using Cygwin effectively](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-effectively.html) page:

> Windows programs do not understand POSIX pathnames, so any arguments that reference the filesystem must be in Windows (or DOS) format or translated.

The [`cygpath`](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath) utility can be used to work-around this issue in some cases, but this won't work inside the Scala REPL, and requires handling a Cygwin environment explicitly in otherwise cross-platform scripts.